# How to prevent custom views from losing state across screen orientation changes

Tags: android, android-activity, state, screen-orientation

I've successfully implemented [`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) for my main `Activity` to save and restore certain critical components across screen orientation changes.

But it seems, my custom views are being re-created from scratch when the orientation changes. This makes sense, although in my case it's inconvenient because the custom view in question is an X/Y plot and the plotted points are stored in the custom view.

Is there a crafty way to implement something similar to `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` for a custom view, or do I need to just implement methods in the custom view which allow me to get and set its "state"?

Answer (score 424, accepted):

You do this by implementing [`View#onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSaveInstanceState%28%29) and [`View#onRestoreInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Parcelable%29) and extending the [`View.BaseSavedState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.BaseSavedState.html) class.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

  private int stateToSave;

  ...

  @Override
  public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    //begin boilerplate code that allows parent classes to save state
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
    //end

    ss.stateToSave = this.stateToSave;

    return ss;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    //begin boilerplate code so parent classes can restore state
    if(!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
      return;
    }

    SavedState ss = (SavedState)state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    //end

    this.stateToSave = ss.stateToSave;
  }

  static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
    int stateToSave;

    SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
      super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in) {
      super(in);
      this.stateToSave = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
      super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
      out.writeInt(this.stateToSave);
    }

    //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
          public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SavedState(in);
          }
          public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SavedState[size];
          }
    };
  }
}
```

The work is split between the View and the View's SavedState class. You should do all the work of reading and writing to and from the `Parcel` in the `SavedState` class. Then your View class can do the work of extracting the state members and doing the work necessary to get the class back to a valid state.

Notes: `View#onSavedInstanceState` and `View#onRestoreInstanceState` are called automatically for you if `View#getId` returns a value >= 0. This happens when you give it an id in xml or call `setId` manually. Otherwise you have to call `View#onSaveInstanceState` and write the Parcelable returned to the parcel you get in `Activity#onSaveInstanceState` to save the state and subsequently read it and pass it to `View#onRestoreInstanceState` from `Activity#onRestoreInstanceState`.

Another simple example of this is the [`CompoundButton`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/widget/CompoundButton.java#CompoundButton.onSaveInstanceState%28%29)

Comment: For those arriving here because this isn't working when using Fragments with the v4 support library, I note that the support library doesn't seem to call the View's onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState for you; you have to explicitly call it yourself from a convenient place in the FragmentActivity or Fragment.

Comment: Note that the CustomView you apply this to should have a unique id set, otherwise they will share state with each other. 
SavedState is stored against the CustomView's id, so if you have multiple CustomViews with the same id, or no id, then the parcel saved in the final CustomView.onSaveInstanceState() will be passed into all the calls to CustomView.onRestoreInstanceState() when the views are restored.

Comment: This method didn't work for me with two custom views (one extending the other).  I kept getting a ClassNotFoundException when restoring my view.  I had to use the Bundle approach in Kobor42's answer.

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` should be `protected` (like their superclass), not `public`. No reason to expose them...

Comment: This **doesn't work well** when saving a custom `BaseSaveState` for a class that extends RecyclerView, you get `Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$SavedState` so you need to do the bug fix that's written down here: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/commit/6f915f7482635c1f4889281c7941a586f2cfb611 (using the ClassLoader of RecyclerView.class to load the super state)

Comment: The recyclerview workaround is here by the author of ObservableScrollView library: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/6f915f7482635c1f4889281c7941a586f2cfb611/observablescrollview/src/main/java/com/github/ksoichiro/android/observablescrollview/ObservableRecyclerView.java#L252-L350

Comment: This seems to save the state, but when I run it writeToParcel is never called. The data is just saved in the fields of SavedState

Comment: @EpicPandaForce have you used this solution ?

Comment: @Nininea yes, although lately I've been using the workaround-version I posted afterwards which contains an explicit "superState".

Comment: I am getting ClassCastException in the OnRestoreInstanceState() method

Comment: Answer from @kobor42 works well with Bundle object, this example gives me ClassCastException i've checked all my custom view id's.

Comment: @rich-schuler May I ask for your help on why a [custom image view looses state on Marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087954/custom-image-view-looses-state-on-marshmallow)?

Comment: This is causing crash with message : 
Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131165303 at offset 3748

Comment: This answer is quite old and I noticed there was a constructor missing that caused crashes on newer Android versions. Have a look at my answer when you are getting a ClassNotFoundException: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59299308/2212770

Comment: The `CREATOR`  field must to be `public static`, otherwise the state can't restore in some case.

Answer (score 482):

I think this is a much simpler version. `Bundle` is a built-in type which implements `Parcelable`

```
public class CustomView extends View
{
  private int stuff; // stuff

  @Override
  public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
  {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("superState", super.onSaveInstanceState());
    bundle.putInt("stuff", this.stuff); // ... save stuff 
    return bundle;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)
  {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) // implicit null check
    {
      Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
      this.stuff = bundle.getInt("stuff"); // ... load stuff
      state = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
    }
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to find.  I had everything set up for saving using bundles, but I was getting an exception.  The missing piece (that I got from you) was that I needed to return the same parcelable to the super that I saved from the super into my custom bundle.

Comment: I'd still move that state variable into it's own static inner class to keep your state variables away from your class vars. But yes Bundle is much simpler than Parcelable

Comment: Why *wouldn't* `onRestoreInstanceState` be called with a Bundle if `onSaveInstanceState` returned a Bundle?

Comment: `OnRestoreInstance` is inherited. We can't change the header. `Parcelable` is just an interface, `Bundle` is an implementation for that.

Comment: Also note that the default implementation in `View` returns null, so if you are implementing an entirely custom view you don't need to bother with the `super.` calls.

Comment: Actually... yes you do. Although the default implementation doesn't save any state, it does note whether you've called it and complains if you don't (presumably a debugging aid). You can just add `super.onSaveInstanceState()` and `super.onRestoreInstanceState(null)` to satisfy it.

Comment: So overall, it's fine like this? :-)

Comment: Thanks this way is much better and avoids BadParcelableException when using the SavedState framework for custom views since the saved state seems to be unable to set the class loader correctly for your custom SavedState!

Comment: I have several instances of the same view in an activity. They all have unique id's  in the xml. But still all of them gets the settings of the last view. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution might be ok, but it is definitely not safe. By implementing this you're assuming that base `View` state is not a `Bundle`. Of course, that is true at the moment, but you are relying on this current implementation fact that is not guaranteed to be true.

Comment: Would there be a reason why `state instanceof Bundle` wouldn't be true in `onRestoreInstanceState` ?

Comment: @Christoffer Helped me: [Saving Android View state correctly](http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/); at the end he uses [dispatchSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchSaveInstanceState(android.util.SparseArray<android.os.Parcelable>)) and [dispatchRestoreInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchRestoreInstanceState(android.util.SparseArray<android.os.Parcelable>))!

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev Why would you have to assume that? Doesn't Bundle implement Parcelable and thus putting a bundle into a bundle is fine?

Comment: @A.Steenbergen `Bundle` is always a `Parcelable`, you are right on this one. But `Parcelable` is not always a `Bundle`.

Comment: But we are returning a Bundle from onSaveInstanceState, which we are getting back in onRestoreInstanceState so we can be sure to receive a bundle

Comment: @A.Steenbergen Why typecheck? What if someone overrides your control, and does something with your "bundle"? Many things could go wrong, and it's a very hard to handle subclassing. Nice way is that they put your bundle into their own parcelable as a "superState", but you can't force this. This seemed a good idea.

Comment: @Snaker It can be false if state is null. If not null, then typecheck should theoretically always be true.

Comment: Be careful. In my case it causes memory leak!

Answer (score 26):

Easy with kotlin

```
@Parcelize
class MyState(val superSavedState: Parcelable?, val loading: Boolean) : View.BaseSavedState(superSavedState), Parcelable


class MyView : View {

    var loading: Boolean = false

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        val superState = super.onSaveInstanceState()
        return MyState(superState, loading)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        val myState = state as? MyState
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(myState?.superSaveState ?: state)

        loading = myState?.loading ?: false
        //redraw
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you gain by extending `View.BaseSavedState` in this case? Does it make any difference?

Comment: also interested in this. i would suggest you try with and without

Answer (score 18):

Here is another variant that uses a mix of the two above methods.
Combining the speed and correctness of `Parcelable` with the simplicity of a `Bundle`:

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // The vars you want to save - in this instance a string and a boolean
    String someString = "something";
    boolean someBoolean = true;
    State state = new State(super.onSaveInstanceState(), someString, someBoolean);
    bundle.putParcelable(State.STATE, state);
    return bundle;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (state instanceof Bundle) {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        State customViewState = (State) bundle.getParcelable(State.STATE);
        // The vars you saved - do whatever you want with them
        String someString = customViewState.getText();
        boolean someBoolean = customViewState.isSomethingShowing());
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(customViewState.getSuperState());
        return;
    }
    // Stops a bug with the wrong state being passed to the super
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(BaseSavedState.EMPTY_STATE); 
}

protected static class State extends BaseSavedState {
    protected static final String STATE = "YourCustomView.STATE";

    private final String someText;
    private final boolean somethingShowing;

    public State(Parcelable superState, String someText, boolean somethingShowing) {
        super(superState);
        this.someText = someText;
        this.somethingShowing = somethingShowing;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return this.someText;
    }

    public boolean isSomethingShowing(){
        return this.somethingShowing;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a ClassCastException... And that's because it needs a public static CREATOR so that it instantiates your `State` from the parcel. Please take a look at: http://charlesharley.com/2012/programming/views-saving-instance-state-in-android/

Answer (score 11):

The answers here already are great, but don't necessarily work for custom ViewGroups. To get all custom Views to retain their state, you must override `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state)` in each class.
You also need to ensure they all have unique ids, whether they're inflated from xml or added programmatically.

What I came up with was remarkably like Kobor42's answer, but the error remained because I was adding the Views to a custom ViewGroup programmatically and not assigning unique ids.

The link shared by mato will work, but it means none of the individual Views manage their own state - the entire state is saved in the ViewGroup methods.

The problem is that when multiple of these ViewGroups are added to a layout, the ids of their elements from the xml are no longer unique (if its defined in xml). At runtime, you can call the static method `View.generateViewId()` to get a unique id for a View. This is only available from API 17.

Here is my code from the ViewGroup (it is abstract, and mOriginalValue is a type variable):

```
public abstract class DetailRow<E> extends LinearLayout {

    private static final String SUPER_INSTANCE_STATE = "saved_instance_state_parcelable";
    private static final String STATE_VIEW_IDS = "state_view_ids";
    private static final String STATE_ORIGINAL_VALUE = "state_original_value";

    private E mOriginalValue;
    private int[] mViewIds;

// ...

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {

        // Create a bundle to put super parcelable in
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(SUPER_INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        // Use abstract method to put mOriginalValue in the bundle;
        putValueInTheBundle(mOriginalValue, bundle, STATE_ORIGINAL_VALUE);
        // Store mViewIds in the bundle - initialize if necessary.
        if (mViewIds == null) {
            // We need as many ids as child views
            mViewIds = new int[getChildCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < mViewIds.length; i++) {
                // generate a unique id for each view
                mViewIds[i] = View.generateViewId();
                // assign the id to the view at the same index
                getChildAt(i).setId(mViewIds[i]);
            }
        }
        bundle.putIntArray(STATE_VIEW_IDS, mViewIds);
        // return the bundle
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {

        // We know state is a Bundle:
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        // Get mViewIds out of the bundle
        mViewIds = bundle.getIntArray(STATE_VIEW_IDS);
        // For each id, assign to the view of same index
        if (mViewIds != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mViewIds.length; i++) {
                getChildAt(i).setId(mViewIds[i]);
            }
        }
        // Get mOriginalValue out of the bundle
        mOriginalValue = getValueBackOutOfTheBundle(bundle, STATE_ORIGINAL_VALUE);
        // get super parcelable back out of the bundle and pass it to
        // super.onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable)
        state = bundle.getParcelable(SUPER_INSTANCE_STATE);
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Custom id is really an issue, but I think it should be handled at the initialization of the view, and not at state save.

Comment: Good point. Do you suggest setting mViewIds in the constructor then overwrite if state is restored?

Comment: This is the most complete answer that is valid for inflatable custom layouts. Unfortunately the answer generates ids only for the direct children but usually that's not the case. E.g. the children could be TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout. In this case the solution would be much more complex.

Answer (score 4):

I had the problem that onRestoreInstanceState restored all my custom views with the state of the last view. I solved it by adding these two methods to my custom view:

```
@Override
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchThawSelfOnly(container);
}
```

Comment: The dispatchFreezeSelfOnly and dispatchThawSelfOnly 
 methods belong to ViewGroup, not View. So in case, your custom View is extended from a build-in View. Your solution is not applicable.

Answer (score 2):

To augment other answers - if you have multiple custom compound views with the same ID and they are all being restored with the state of the last view on a configuration change, all you need to do is tell the view to only dispatch save/restore events to itself by overriding a couple of methods.

```
class MyCompoundView : ViewGroup {

    ...

    override fun dispatchSaveInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>) {
        dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container)
    }

    override fun dispatchRestoreInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>) {
        dispatchThawSelfOnly(container)
    }
}
```

For an explanation of what is happening and why this works, [see this blog post](https://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/).  Basically your compound view's children's view IDs are shared by each compound view and state restoration gets confused.  By only dispatching state for the compound view itself, we prevent their children from getting mixed messages from other compound views.

Answer (score 2):

I found that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542895/2212770) was causing some crashes on Android versions 9 and 10. I think it's a good approach but when I was looking at some [Android code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/viewpager2/src/main/java/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.java#412) I found out it was missing a constructor. The answer is quite old so at the time there probably was no need for it. When I added the missing constructor and called it from the creator the crash was fixed.

So here is the edited code:

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    private int stateToSave;

    ...

    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);

        // your custom state
        ss.stateToSave = this.stateToSave;

        return ss;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container)
    {
        dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

        // your custom state
        this.stateToSave = ss.stateToSave;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container)
    {
        dispatchThawSelfOnly(container);
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        int stateToSave;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            this.stateToSave = in.readInt();
        }

        // This was the missing constructor
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        SavedState(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader)
        {
            super(in, loader);
            this.stateToSave = in.readInt();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeInt(this.stateToSave);
        }    
        
        public static final Creator<SavedState> CREATOR =
            new ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState>() {
          
            // This was also missing
            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in, ClassLoader loader)
            {
                return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N ? new SavedState(in, loader) : new SavedState(in);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in, null);
            }

            @Override
            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the code yourself? The method `dispatchFreezeSelfOnly` and `dispatchFreezeSelfOnly` are belong to `ViewGroup`, not `View`.

Comment: @zeleven You're right, I used code from another answer and didn't edit it correctly. You should just extend `LinearLayout` or `ViewGroup` instead of `View` and it will be fine. I do use a slightly altered version of this solution in my app and it works fine. I Will try to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Fletcher Johns answer I came up with:

- custom layout
- can inflate from XML
- is able to save/restore direct and indirect children. I improved @Fletcher Johns' answer to save the ids in String->Id map instead of IntArray.
- the only small drawback is that you must declare your saveable child views beforehand.

```kotlin
open class AddressView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
        defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {

    protected lateinit var countryInputLayout: TextInputLayout
    protected lateinit var countryAutoCompleteTextView: CountryAutoCompleteTextView
    protected lateinit var cityInputLayout: TextInputLayout
    protected lateinit var cityEditText: CityEditText
    protected lateinit var postCodeInputLayout: TextInputLayout
    protected lateinit var postCodeEditText: PostCodeEditText
    protected lateinit var streetInputLayout: TextInputLayout
    protected lateinit var streetEditText: StreetEditText
    
    init {
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        val view = inflate(context, R.layout.view_address, this)

        orientation = VERTICAL

        countryInputLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.countryInputLayout)
        countryAutoCompleteTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.countryAutoCompleteTextView)

        streetInputLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.streetInputLayout)
        streetEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.streetEditText)

        cityInputLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.cityInputLayout)
        cityEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.cityEditText)

        postCodeInputLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.postCodeInputLayout)
        postCodeEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.postCodeEditText)
    }

    // Declare your direct and indirect child views that need to be saved
    private val childrenToSave get() = mapOf<String, View>(
            "coutryIL" to countryInputLayout,
            "countryACTV" to countryAutoCompleteTextView,
            "streetIL" to streetInputLayout,
            "streetET" to streetEditText,
            "cityIL" to cityInputLayout,
            "cityET" to cityEditText,
            "postCodeIL" to postCodeInputLayout,
            "postCodeET" to postCodeEditText,
    )
    private var viewIds: HashMap<String, Int>? = null

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(): Parcelable? {
        // Create a bundle to put super parcelable in
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putParcelable(SUPER_INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState())
        // Store viewIds in the bundle - initialize if necessary.
        if (viewIds == null) {
            childrenToSave.values.forEach { view -> view.id = generateViewId() }
            viewIds = HashMap<String, Int>(childrenToSave.mapValues { (key, view) -> view.id })
        }

        bundle.putSerializable(STATE_VIEW_IDS, viewIds)

        return bundle
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(state: Parcelable?) {
        // We know state is a Bundle:
        val bundle = state as Bundle
        // Get mViewIds out of the bundle
        viewIds = bundle.getSerializable(STATE_VIEW_IDS) as HashMap<String, Int>
        // For each id, assign to the view of same index
        if (viewIds != null) {
            viewIds!!.forEach { (key, id) -> childrenToSave[key]!!.id = id }
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(SUPER_INSTANCE_STATE))
    }

    companion object {
        private const val SUPER_INSTANCE_STATE = "saved_instance_state_parcelable"
        private const val STATE_VIEW_IDS = "state_view_ids"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, you can also use a [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel). Make your data model extend `ViewModel`, and then you can use `ViewModelProviders` to get the same instance of your model every time the Activity is recreated:

```
class MyData extends ViewModel {
    // have all your properties with getters and setters here
}

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // the first time, ViewModelProvider will create a new MyData
        // object. When the Activity is recreated (e.g. because the screen
        // is rotated), ViewModelProvider will give you the initial MyData
        // object back, without creating a new one, so all your property
        // values are retained from the previous view.
        myData = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyData.class);

        ...
    }
}
```

To use `ViewModelProviders`, add the following to `dependencies` in `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
```

Note that your `MyActivity` extends `FragmentActivity` instead of just extending `Activity`.

You can read more about ViewModels here:

- [Android Developer Guide, Handle configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)
- [Android Developer Guide, Saving UI States, Use ViewModel to handle configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states#use_viewmodel_to_handle_configuration_changes)
- [Tutorial ViewModels : A Simple Example](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e)

Comment: Please have a look at [Android ViewModel Architecture Component considered harmful](https://www.techyourchance.com/android-viewmodel-architecture-component-harmful)

Comment: @JJD I agree with the article you posted, one still has to handle save and restore properly. `ViewModel` is especially handy if you have large data sets to retain during a state change, such as a screen rotation. I prefer using the `ViewModel` instead of writing it into `Application` because it's clearly scoped, and I can have multiple Activities of the same Application behaving correctly.