# Android - View reuse in fragment, in a Single-Activity Multi-Fragment case

Tags: android, android-fragments

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5451620/446508) deals with the memory leak caused by saving the View instance returned by a fragment, allowing the onCreateView of a fragment to return the same View under certain circumstances. The conclusion there is that the saved View will hold the Activity (via Context), never allowing it to release - resulting in a memory leak.

My question in this context, is: If I'm implementing my whole app in a single activity, could I consider this problem as irrelevant? Or are there other considerations not to save it?

Thanks! Danny.

Edit: To make things worse, what would be the case if the View is given as a parameter to the Fragment constructor?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not irrelevant - this same issue could hit your app in the normal Activity lifecycle.

The best solution is to use the `View.onSaveInstanceState()`, and `View.onRestoreSavedInstanceState(Bundle)` methods to handle restoring your Views properly. Unless you're doing something particularly esoteric, these should be all you need.

Comment: Thanks! I think my case might be quite esoteric, as you said. The problem is that I very much want to save the `View` itself, and not just a few state params. The reason is that the whole view hierarchy I wish to save is created in runtime and handed to the `Fragment`, through a slightly complicated mechanism, and recreating it may be very inefficient. I'm not sure I see where in the lifecycle of the Activity this may happen? Wouldn't the worse case be that the activity is killed, in which case the Fragment dies with it? Thanks.