# Wrong values after rotation when more components with the same IDs are in one layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created a deletable `EditText`. Here is the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/cacEditText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingRight="35dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cacClearButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that when I put more of these into one layout and rotate to landscape, they all suddenly have the same value. I suppose it is because the system restores the values by ID and each component consists of elements of the same IDs. How can I solve this problem?

**More info:**

deletable `EditText` (`cz.kns.uome.component.CleanAndClearEditText`) in a layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/cz.kns.uome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <cz.kns.uome.component.CleanAndClearEditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contactPickerButton"
                    app:hint="@string/person_name"
                    app:type="textPersonName" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/contactPickerButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/select_contact"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_dropdown" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <cz.kns.uome.component.CleanAndClearEditText
                android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hint="@string/person_email_opt"
                app:type="textEmailAddress" />

            <cz.kns.uome.component.CleanAndClearEditText
                android:id="@+id/descriptionEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hint="@string/description_opt"
                app:type="text" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:text="@string/save" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/cancel" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**java class**

```
public class CleanAndClearEditText extends RelativeLayout {

    private final EditText editText;
    private final Button clearButton;

    public CleanAndClearEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.clean_and_clear_edit_text, this);

        TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ClearAndCleanEditText);

        // ?????
        // I have to somehow access that edittext here but static id does not work
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cacEditText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        editText.setHint(typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ClearAndCleanEditText_hint));

        String type = typedArray.getString(R.styleable.ClearAndCleanEditText_type);
        if (type != null) {
            editText.setInputType(InputTypes.get(type));
        }

        clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cacClearButton);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(clearButtonListener);
    }
    // rest ommited
}
```

[image: Normal state]
[image: Rotated]

Comment: I didn't understand your question. If you put more of these into one layout, you should have different id's.

Comment: Please look at the updated question

Comment: You'll have to save the state for your custom `View`. Here is a link with a detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes .

Comment: @Luksprog That is not the problem. If I used this I wouldn't have to create my own component because it wouldn't help me at all

Comment: Oddly, I've just experienced this same phenomenon. Can you please explain further why this is happening, @Tomas? Is it simply because of the ID's in the xml layout you inflate?

Comment: @Luksprog If you could explain it too, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps:

```
public class CleanAndClearEditText extends RelativeLayout {

    private final EditText editText;
    private final Button clearButton;

    public CleanAndClearEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.clean_and_clear_edit_text, this);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) getChildAt(0); // consider using a merge tag in R.layout.clean_and_clear_edit_text instead of the parent RelativeLayout
        //clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cacClearButton);
        clearButton = (Button) rl.getChildAt(1);
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        //editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cacEditText);
        editText = (EditText) rl.getChildAt(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);
        ss.stateToSave = editText.getText().toString();
        return ss;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        editText.setText(ss.stateToSave);
    }

    static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        String stateToSave;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
            super(superState);
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            stateToSave = in.readString();
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeString(stateToSave);
        }

        // required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
            public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new SavedState(in);
            }

            public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                return new SavedState[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and the modified `R.layout.clean_and_clear_edit_text` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingRight="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:**
The main part of the code is from the question I posted as a comment.

Comment: I tried to manually set IDs which worked fine but it was a little bit hack. This one is longer but better and safer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm running on this issue, and I was able to "solve" this, by removing all views in the layout that contains the custom views, implement this:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // retain your data in the bundle then remove views
    layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
}
```

So you can get your data back from the bundle in the onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see you are inflating custom code and inserting it into a linearlayout. You should use a ListView and implement your ListAdapter. You can customize your ListItem to fit your needs.
That's the way I would do it.

Comment: you can add different views into a listview.

Comment: listview is useless, this is not a list of components... it's a reusable component which can be everywhere