# Two SearchViews in one Activity and screen rotation

Tags: java, android

I have two SearchViews in one xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/my_first_custom_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </SearchView>

   <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/my_second_custom_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_first_custom_view" >
   </SearchView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I inflate this layout to my MainActivity by setContentView(). Then I call methods 
setQuery() for each other.

Everything is ok until a screen rotation. **When I rotate the screen every searchView has text "World" instead "Hello" and "World".**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SearchView firstSearchView = (SearchView)     findViewById(R.id.my_first_custom_view);
        SearchView secondSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.my_second_custom_view);

        firstSearchView.setQuery("Hello!", false);
        secondSearchView.setQuery("World", false);
    }
}
```

Someone can explain what's going wrong ?

Comment: Is this the only reference your searchviews get is in onCreate? I'm assuming no.. if not then you may want to post that relevant code

Comment: I tried your code and have the same behavior as you... so everything to reproduce the problem is in the post

Comment: Yes, it is the only one reference. I don't use it anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `SearchView` uses as its content the view resulted from inflating a layout file. As a result, all the `SearchViews` used in the layout of an activity(like your case) will have as content, views with the same ids. When Android will try to save the state to handle the configuration change it will see that the `EditTexts` from the `SearchViews` have the same id and it will restore the same state for all of them.

The simplest way to handle this issue is to use the `Activity`'s `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // state for the first SearchView
    outState.putString("sv1", firstSearchView.getQuery().toString());
    // state for the second SearchView
    outState.putString("sv2", secondSearchView.getQuery().toString());
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // properly set the state to balance Android's own restore mechanism
    firstSearchView.setQuery(savedInstanceState.getString("sv1"), false);
    secondSearchView.setQuery(savedInstanceState.getString("sv2"), false);
}
```

Also have a look at this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes).

Comment: Thank you. It works ;). Very important in this case is restore instance in onRestoreInstanceState() method. When i do this in onCreate, it does not work. Probably values "Hello" and "World" from onCreate are overrwriten in onRestore method.

Answer (score -1):

One way to alleviate this problem is to capture the orientation event change with your activity and then set the query again on your two search views.

Comment: Can you write something more obout this?

Comment: Its not too complicated, Google how to listen to the orientation change in your activity and then just re-configure your two search views.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to manifest in activity in which you are having two `SearchView`

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: @loocash1989 check my answer and notify me whether this is helpful or not.

Comment: well ...this is not an answer to the question. It's kind of workaround but it has some drawbacks.

Comment: It is not good solution for me, but I admit that it works too. I was looking for bug inside SearchView. Moreover my Activity should be recreated after screen rotation and I don't want change its default behavior. Thanks for your answer. I think it may be helpfull for somebody.