# Layout not maintaining state in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have seen many questions regarding saving layout changes on orientation in Fragments but not able to work it out.
I have a Fragment Activity. in it's xml i have only one element :-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and in the activity i am calling the fragment :-

```
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ForgotPassword fragment = new ForgotPassword();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

in **ForgotPassword** fragment, i am creating a two buttons and an edittext. Now on one of the button click, i am hiding the other button and the edittext.

When i rotate the screen, the layout is re created and i can see all my widgets even after i have put `setRetainInstance(true)`

**My widgets are not maintaining their states. If they are invisible they should remain invisible when screen is rotated**

Comment: So have you add configchanges for your Fragment Activity from where your Fragments being called?

Comment: I have added configChanges="screenSize". Don't tell me to add orientation because that is not the solution. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Visibility is not part of the transient `View` state that is saved/restored during a screen rotation.

The saving is handled by `View.onSaveInstanceState()` and its overrides. The default implementation of [View.onSaveInstanceState()](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L12762) is as follows:

```
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    mPrivateFlags |= PFLAG_SAVE_STATE_CALLED;
    return BaseSavedState.EMPTY_STATE;
}
```

i.e. nothing is saved for you by default. Views such as `TextView` will [save additional state](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java#L3491) (e.g. the current text, if [setFreezesText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFreezesText%28boolean%29) is called with *true*). I am not aware of any default View that saves the visibility state.

If you want the visibility state to be preserved, you will have to save it yourself. Here are some options:

1. Create a subclass of your desired View and override `View.onSaveInstanceState` saving visibility into the bundle. Approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes).
2. Override `Fragment.onSaveInstanceState` in the Fragment containing your Views, saving visibility into the bundle.
3. Use `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)`, and maintain the visibility state within the Fragment as an instance variable, reapplying the state after the View has been created again. Warning: this does not preserve the state if your process is killed while in the background, the other two options do.

Answer (score 1):

WORKING SOLUTION

As you are using setRetainInstance(true)

the fragment will retain state. Apart from this you have to figure out a way to preserve the visibility states of your views and recreate the view in the onViewCreated() method of the fragment.

The important point to note here is that while you recreate the view using the retained visibility settings, it should NOT be done in onCreateView().

In the below code snippet, i am retaining radio button checked value in "rbChecked" variable using setRetainInstance(true) and then later on after orientation change the rbChecked value is used to recreate the visibility state in onViewCreated() method.

```
public class CaptureReminderFragment extends Fragment {

     private String rbChecked;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.capture_reminder_fragment, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    if(rbChecked != null) {
        switch (rbChecked) {
            case "daily":
                layoutEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutReminderDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutSpecificReminderName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutNakshatra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutRashi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "events":
                layoutEvents.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutReminderDay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutSpecificReminderName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutNakshatra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutRashi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case "specific":
                layoutSpecificReminderName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutReminderDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                layoutNakshatra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutRashi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            default:
                layoutEvents.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutReminderDay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutSpecificReminderName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutNakshatra.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                layoutRashi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
        }
    }

}

}
```