# onCreate() called after Home button click and coming back to app

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I tested my app in different phones. There is a strange thing. In all phones, the `onCreate()` never runs when I send my app to background using home button and come back to it. But in Nexus, the `onCreate()` method runs. The whole of my view is recreated which I want to avoid. I don't know how to save the views and other info in `savedInstanceState`. How to avoid rerunning `onCreate()`? Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Even in activity life cycle, `onResume()` only is supposed to be executed after coming back to the activity from background.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you checked onResume(), the only thing that can reRun the onCreate() is that your app is exited somehow!

Comment: @Saqib No my app is not exited. It is a mp3 player and keeps playing even in background. As mentioned in the life cycle, maybe my activity is destroyed by the system.

Comment: Then your activity must be destroyed by some other activity or process. As you can see that in lifecycle process your activity might have been killed by some other more priority process. Are you using a service for player?

Comment: @Saqib No I am using async task in an activity

Comment: @Saqib I know I must use service to play, but it makes updating the player view in my app more difficult. I guess I must use broadcaster too

Answer (score 1):

> But in Nexus, the onCreate method runs. The whole of my view is recreated which I want to avoid.

You shouldn't make assumptions on whether `onCreate()` will be called or no. Prepare your app for a situation, when system destroys app's process, which would initiate `onCreate()` to be called upon opening app. This can be easily tested with ["Do not keep activities"](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-b1_z6j_NH5E/V3yasKUoIYI/AAAAAAAADCs/mQ2e6oKslLQFjBN2VOL9akU_NSzQ_aq2QCLcB/s400/enable-do-not-keep-activities.jpg) developer mode.

> I don't know how to save the views and other info in savedInstanceState.

If you use framework views (e.g. `Button`, `TextView`) which have `id` associated with them (e.g. `android:id="@+id/some_id"`), system will take care of saving their state, you should **not** care about it. If you have custom components you should take care of [implementing that logics yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542895/1083957).

> How to avoid rerunning onCreate?

If system performed `onCreate`, that means it had good reason to do that. In other words, you cannot tell "please, do not call onCreate, jump to onResume right away".

Comment: You are right. I learned a lot after that. Thanks for the answer.