# Can't implement Parcelable because I can't make the CREATOR field static

Tags: java, android, parcelable

The `Parcelable` docs say that the `CREATOR` field must be static, but when I try to implement it this way I get the error "Inner classes cannot have static declarations".

I attempted to resolve this by putting my `CategoryButton` in a separate class (not declaring it as an inner class in `MainActivity`) but then I couldn't call `getApplicationContext()` in the constructor to pass to the super.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private class CategoryButton extends Button implements Parcelable{
        private ArrayList<CategoryButton> buttons = null;
        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = null;
        public CategoryButton(Context context){
            super(context);
        };
        public void setButtons(ArrayList<CategoryButton> buttons){
            this.buttons = buttons;
        }
        public void setParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params){
            this.params = params;
        }
        public ArrayList<CategoryButton> getButtons(){
            return this.buttons;
        }
        public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getParams(){
            return this.params;
        }



        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            out.writeList(buttons);
        }
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<CategoryButton> CREATOR // *** inner classes cannot have static declarations
                = new Parcelable.Creator<CategoryButton>() {
            public CategoryButton createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new CategoryButton(in); // *** 'package.MainActivity.this' cannot be referenced from a static context
            }

            public CategoryButton[] newArray(int size) {
                return new CategoryButton[size];
            }
        };

        private CategoryButton(Parcel in) {
            super(getApplicationContext());
            in.readList(buttons, null);
        }

    }

// ...other activity code
```

Comment: I dont understand why you do extend button and implement Parcerable

Comment: Because for my app I need to have a button that has a property `buttons` that contains other buttons...

Comment: Why do you need to implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: Because I need to pass the `buttons` property to an `Intent` as an `extra` and it's an `ArrayList<CategoryButton>` so `CategoryButton` needs to implement `Parcelable` in order for me to call `putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)` on the `Intent`.before I pass it to `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set your `CategoryButton` as inner static, i.e.

```
private static class CategoryButton extends Button implements Parcelable {
    ...
```

Comment: I just tried this and although it fixes the `CREATOR` field problem, it makes it so I can't call `getApplicationContext()` to pass to the super in the constructor.

Comment: Button is a view, i.e. change your call to context as `super(getContext());`

Comment: Hmm now I get the error `Cannot reference 'View.getContext()' before supertype constructor has been called`

Comment: Well, it is a custom constructor, just replace it with `private CategoryButton(@NonNull Context context, Parcel in) {...`. But depends of your logic, you may need to change the way you are calling this private constructor.

Comment: I just tried changing the signature of the constructor as you describe and then calling it from `createFromParcel()` like this: `return new CategoryButton(getContext(), in);` but then I'm back to the error `Non-static method 'getContext()' cannot be referenced from a static context` :\

Comment: Please look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes/3542895#3542895) how to restore from `Parcelable`