# how to properly restore view state after rotations

Tags: android, android-view

I am tring to handle rotation for  [complex view](https://github.com/frakc/DraggablePanel/blob/develop/draggablepanel/src/main/java/com/github/pedrovgs/DraggableView.java) manually, including restoring the propper position and size. At this moment i am trying to do it in `onLayout` (better ideas are velcome). Sometimes it works good, but often first rotation is misplaces or view is drawn without childs.

```
private int oldOrientation = -1;

  /**
   * Override method to configure the dragged view and secondView layout properly.
   */
  @Override protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    Log.e("mylayout", "onLayout " + df.format(new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())));
    if (isInEditMode()) {
      super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    } else {
      dragView.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
      if (isDragViewAtTop() && (oldOrientation != getResources().getConfiguration().orientation || oldOrientation == -1)) {
        dragView.layout(left, top, right, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        secondView.layout(left, transformer.getOriginalHeight(), right, bottom);
        ViewHelper.setY(dragView, top);
        ViewHelper.setY(secondView, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        ViewHelper.setX(dragView, left);
        ViewHelper.setX(secondView, left);
        oldOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
      } else if (isClosedAtLeft() && (
          oldOrientation != getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
              || oldOrientation == -1)) {
        dragView.layout(left, top, right, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        secondView.layout(left, transformer.getOriginalHeight(), right, bottom);
        ViewHelper.setY(dragView, top);
        ViewHelper.setY(secondView, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        ViewHelper.setX(dragView, left);
        ViewHelper.setX(secondView, left);
        closeToLeft();
        oldOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
      } else if (isClosedAtRight() && (
          oldOrientation != getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
              || oldOrientation == -1)) {
        dragView.layout(left, top, right, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        secondView.layout(left, transformer.getOriginalHeight(), right, bottom);
        ViewHelper.setY(dragView, top);
        ViewHelper.setY(secondView, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        ViewHelper.setX(dragView, left);
        ViewHelper.setX(secondView, left);
        closeToRight();
        oldOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
      } else if ((oldOrientation != getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
          || oldOrientation == -1)) {
        dragView.layout(left, top, right, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        secondView.layout(left, transformer.getOriginalHeight(), right, bottom);
        ViewHelper.setY(dragView, top);
        ViewHelper.setY(secondView, transformer.getOriginalHeight());
        ViewHelper.setX(dragView, left);
        ViewHelper.setX(secondView, left);
        smoothSlideTo(SLIDE_BOTTOM);
        oldOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
      }
      dragView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
  }
```

In this code, i try to restore initial stte after rotation, when onLayout is called and then move it to place, the view was before rotation (there are 4 states, out of creen to left, out of screen to right, top of scren or bottom right corner).

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    package="com.github.pedrovgs.sample"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <!-- Application configuration -->

    <application
        android:name=".DraggablePanelApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Maps API KEY -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC1rMU-mkhoyTvBIdTnYU0dss0tU9vtK48" />

        <!-- Main Activity -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Places sample -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.PlacesSampleActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

            android:label="@string/places_sample_activity_title" />

        <!-- TV Shows sample -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TvShowsActivity"
            android:label="@string/tv_shows_sample_activity_title" />


        <!-- Youtube Sample -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.YoutubeSampleActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

            android:label="@string/youtube_sample_activity_title" />


        <!-- Video Sample -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.VideoSampleActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

            android:label="@string/video_sample_activity_title" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

sample activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:draggable_panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fl_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <!-- Movie Thumbnail -->

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/iv_thumbnail"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      style="@style/image_view"/>

  <!-- DraggablePanel -->

  <com.github.pedrovgs.DraggablePanel
      android:id="@+id/draggable_panel"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      draggable_panel:x_scale_factor="@dimen/x_scale_factor"
      draggable_panel:y_scale_factor="@dimen/y_scale_factor"
      draggable_panel:top_fragment_height="@dimen/top_fragment_height"
      draggable_panel:top_fragment_margin_right="@dimen/top_fragment_margin"
      draggable_panel:top_fragment_margin_bottom="@dimen/top_fragment_margin"
      draggable_panel:enable_horizontal_alpha_effect="false"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: why are u not using manifest for it..? You can ignore the rotation if you are not doing something special on rotation...

Comment: @sourabhbans are you about `            android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
` ? i use it, thats why i am asking about manual handle of view (not activity)

Comment: Ok.. sory i misunderstood..

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/a/3542895/1377145 ?

Comment: @HugoGresse yes, but like i stated in bounty saveInstanceState is not called on manueal rotation handle

Comment: can you add your manifest to the question?

Comment: Why do you manage view restore manually inside onLayout? I think it is easier and more correct to remove android:configChanges tag from manifest and handle common case with onSaveInstanceState & onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: @Alexandr my view containe surface which  show strong visual lag, when recreated on normal rotation flow. So there is no feeling that drawing goes without pause. Also youtubeplayer stops on normal rotation

Comment: @HugoGresse I added manifest

Comment: Can't you use Exoplayer and their AspectRatio framelayout https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/AspectRatioFrameLayout.java

Comment: @HugoGresse the views task to handle view minimisation and gragging similar to youtube

Comment: @HugoGresse are you asking how is it defined in xml?

Comment: @HugoGresse id is definded in xml

Comment: If your onRestoreInstanceState is not called make sure you have overrode a proper method onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) not a onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState). The second one is called only on API23

Comment: Awesome stuff. Are you the same person who forked the original project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extended a `ViewGroup` instead of a `View` and yet haven't added any `child` to the `DraggableView` in the xml or in the code. I don't see any `addChild` or any child related code in `DraggableView`. You have used `topFragment`, `bottomFragment`, etc.. and you used `addFragmentToView()` to make fragment transaction inside the `ViewGroup`. Bad idea!

I know it's hard and time consuming. But you need to step back and think about the Design of this view. I would strongly suggest you treat these `topFragment`,etc.. as children to the `DraggableView`, and not have a `FragmentManager` inside this View and perform `addTransaction`.

Once you start adding the fragments as children to your `ViewGroup`, lot of complications will just go away. I say this from my past experience. `onLayout()` is used to arrange the `Child Views` inside the `ViewGroup`. Once you rotate the device, `onLayout()` will again be called and will arrange the child views as you want. It would be very simple. Dragging operation will be made much simple once you start conceptualizing like this.

If you think having `Framgents` as child in the `ViewGroup` is absurd, kindly look at the `ViewPager` code [here](https://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/trunk/compatibility/AndroidSupportV2/src/android/support/v2/view/ViewPager.java?r=3488). This uses fragments as input but still treat them as children to the layout.

1. Try to handle all stuff related to position in `onLayout()` itself.
2. Do not save position data in `onSaveInstanceState()`. Save only the `text` or `drawable` data in this.
3. It's always advisable not to override `onCofigurationChanged()`.

You may not be able to do this now, but in the longer run, you might want to refactor and do it this way.

Remember the true purpose of `onLayout()`:

> Called from layout when this view should assign a size and position to
>   each of its children. Derived classes with children should override
>   this method and call layout on each of their children.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to go deep in Laying out your `View`s you do not need this for your `View`'s `Activity`

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

if that is set after rotation, android care less of whether to recreate your `Activity` hence re-drawing,-re-measuring,-re-positioning re-etc-etc.

so if you start your app with an `ImageView` placement [10 100]  after rotation boy your `ImageView` will be assumed to be placed [10 100] sometimes it might even give you weird offscreen co-ordinates.

Comment: sithout it, there will be pause in video stream

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onConfigrationChange()` override method 
this method will handle the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're creating your own custom view. If so, you should use standard mechanisms provided by View class.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    // Restore state
}

@Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    // Save state
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a good way

```
@Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
        return new YourParcelableObject(superState, yourValues);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        YourParcelableObject savedState = (SavedState) state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());

        //restote other values from YourParcelableObject
    }
```