# how onSaveInstanceState keep the latest state of the Activity even if the Activity destroyed or stopped

Tags: android, android-activity

In this class, i am Overriding both of onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods, it enabled me to keep the last state of the activity while rotating screen, however, if i **navigated to another activity**, or i went to **Home** of my device, it doesn't keep the latest state and start a new state.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("mylist",mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist")!=null) {

        savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");
        update_START();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }else {
        update_START();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

can any body tell me what should i add to inforce my Activity to keep its latest state even if the activity has been destroyed, should i add any block of code to any other activities?

my onPostExecute method is as follows:

```
@Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<MovieEntity> result) {
        mAdapter=null;
        mAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(getBaseContext(), result);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

This is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.prof_mohamed.movieapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<receiver
    android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
    android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="Pop Movies">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailActivity" android:label="MovieDetail"></activity>
</application>
```

It supposed that when i navigate between activities or even between other applications, then return to my first running app, it should restore its latest saved state before starting navigation to other Activities or apps.

Comment: post your manifest please

Comment: @DavidWasser i have edited my post to include my Manifest.xml file, please review the current state of my Manifest file.

Comment: Have you enabled the  developer option "do not keep activities"? Please add logging to `onDestroy()` in each of your activities and see if this method is being called. I see nothing strange in your code or in your manifest. Are you testing on a real device or emulator?

Comment: how is the variable `mAdapter` declared? How an where is it in initialized?

Comment: the mAdapter is initialized in th onPostExecute, u can review my post again, u will find my onPostExecute method with the mAdapter initialization

Comment: i am testing on a real device not emulator

Comment: Dear @DavidWasser in developer option "do not keep activities" was enabled, i have disabled it, and now every thing is running, saving state in Activities navigation, Home button navigation, and screen rotation.......... Thanks very much dear .. Your comment is the best Solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in developer options "do not keep activities" option was enabled, you have to make it disabled, and now every thing is running, saving state in Activities navigation, Home button navigation, and screen rotation besides Overriding both of these methods

@Override

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist")!=null) {

        savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");
    }
}
```

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");

}

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");
```

}

will make your app save its state completely ...

Comment: By disabling do not keep activity your app may run fine for now. But you need to take care of this case also. This option is provide to test app for cases where system kill activity and claim memory and recreate it. Please search for it and study about this. Debug your code call these mthod onRestoreInstanceState and onSaveInstnaceState after disabling do not keep activtiy option

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save state for later use, you can write necessary data in either sqlite db or persistence storage. By this kind of design you have to save all data required to make activity in same state. There are other options also but saving data in permanent storage fit for your need and safe. (Assuming you want an activity always persist it state event it destroyed) OnSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState automatically save views state (view with id defined in xml) not only for rotation but also for activity kill by system for memory requirement. So you have to save view state also. (for ex edittext with entered data or selected check box etc)

Comment: Excuse me dear, can u comment here with a complete resource like a video describing what you say. Thanks

Comment: I said a lot things, for which part you need clarification please mention, so I can provide you link

Comment: I use a a custom Adapter to inflate image poster on my recyclerview. i wanna have a link for saving state for this recyclerview for screen rotation, Activities and Home button navigation using sqlite for saving view state or whatever

Comment: Can you please share adapter code? Want to know your list/array data model to provide efficient solution.

Comment: (Assuming you already know and implemented this)For orientation change follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes

Comment: For saving data permanently try this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: please, review my post to see my mAdapter variable initialization in the onPostExecute method

Comment: answer is in disabling "do not keep activities" in developer options... thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are not using the **savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist")** correctly, you should save and cast the object in a variable and use it:

*List list = (List) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");*

At this point, The bundle is restored only in the onCreate method (for example on rotation when the activity is destroyed then re-created)

To support saving the instance state on activity navigation or when the home button is pressed (which call onStop then onStart), put the same logic in the if condition inside the **onRestoreInstanceState** which is called after **onStart**.

Comment: Dear Karim, 
when i put both of the following logics in the onRestoreInsatnceState inside if condition
1. mAdapter = (ImagesAdapter) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");
2. list = (ArrayList) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist");
mAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(getBaseContext(), list);

In reality, it doesn't make any sense, it doesn't influence saving state

Comment: answer is in disabling "do not keep activities" in developer options... thanks very much