# Viewpager doesn't save fragment state if a custom textview is used

Tags: android

Viewpager doesn't save it's fragments state if a fragment contains a textview which has custom font set to it. How do I prevent this?

```
public class SansFontTextView extends TextView {
public SansFontTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setUpTypeFace();
}

public SansFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setUpTypeFace();
}

public SansFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setUpTypeFace();
}

private void setUpTypeFace(){

    Typeface openSansBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),  "fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf");

    setTypeface(openSansBold);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you used `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I did , that textview is used in xml

Comment: if I use a regular textview instead , everything works well

Comment: Have u tried regular textview with font assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

You have not instructed what to do with your custom component, when system saves their state, i.e. you haven't specified what to save in `onSavedInstanceState()` and what to restore in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

If your custom view wants to save that information it should override those callback in order to survive destruction. Otherwise your custom `TextView` will be saved as an ordinary `TextView` (i.e. only `super.onSavedInstanceState()` will be called), and your properties that you have defined in your custom class will be lost.

See how to do that [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542895/1083957).