# Saving state of UI in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making a to-do list app and after user presses the button I create a new GridLayout(and all the data about time and name of the task inside of it) and add it into my RelativeLayout. How do I save those GridLayouts in UI so after the activity is destroyed and launched again those layouts are there.

After pressing the button I trigger the Create Activity method

```
public void CreateActivity(String name,int hours, int minutes,int i)
{
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relparams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,i);
    relparams.setMargins(0,50,0,100);
   Glayouts.add(new GridLayout(this));
    Glayouts.get(i+1).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    Glayouts.get(i+1).setMinimumWidth(relative.getWidth());
    Glayouts.get(i+1).setId(i+1);
    Glayouts.get(i+1).setPadding(10,0,0,0);
    GridLayout.LayoutParams namee = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    namee.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
    namee.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
    namee.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    final TextView Actname = new TextView(this);
    Actname.setText(name);

    GridLayout.LayoutParams checkbox = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    checkbox.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(1);
    checkbox.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(0);
    checkbox.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    CheckBox check = new CheckBox(this);
    // ADDING TO LAYOUT
    Glayouts.get(i+1).addView(Actname,namee);
    Glayouts.get(i+1).addView(check,checkbox);

    relative.addView(Glayouts.get(i+1),relparams);
```

Comment: Can you explain it more clearly, or post any UI. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I added my method that adds the gridlayout. Basically it creates a gridlayout inside a relative one, but when I shut down my app and launch it again my relative layout is empty again. How do I save that GridLayout so its gonna be there after launching the app again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically when you `extends View`, then you can also override `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods, where you must provide your own `SavedState` class that typically `extends BaseSavedState`. You can find info on that [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542895/2413303)

In your case, your layout is dynamic, therefore this doesn't really work. To tell you the *truth*, your layout probably shouldn't be constructed this way, you should be rendering the grid using a RecyclerView based on a "model" that describes this layout, render the items of the grid via the `RecyclerView.Adapter`, and you should persist either the "model", or the data you use to construct this model along with the user-inputted state so that you can re-construct the model that will be rendered via your RecyclerView.

You can read more about RecyclerView [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40587169/2413303).

You can read more about data persistence [**here**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#persist-data).

You can read about using `onSaveInstanceState` to save data in Activities/Fragments across config change and process death (but not finishing then restarting the app) [**here**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states).

Answer (score 0):

You can’t. The best way to save state is to use some persistence mechanism, for example database (I’d recommend [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as it is officially supported by Google).

After clicking a button, you should put all the needed information (name, hours, minutes) in the database and when Activity is created, you can read all persisted data and - basing on it - create all needed layouts again.

Another option is storing data in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) - it is much easier to setup, so you can also start with this solution. Please note, I'm suggesting it as a first step in the world of persistency in Android, not as a preferred solution for storing data.

Comment: Can you explain downvoting?

Comment: Views do have a built-in state persistence mechanism, so "you can't" is a stretch, even if it is not applicable here (because of programatically constructing the layout). Also because you said "store data in SharedPreferences" which is honestly just a "no-no" in general. It might be a key-value store, but in reality it *is* just a big XML file.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, let me refer to it:
1. OP asked for a mechanism for keeping states, even after app is launched again (has explained it in comment). Build-in view state persistence state does not provide such functionality.
2. I'm also sure that Room (or Realm or other solutions) is much better than `SharedPreferences` for real apps (I've even recommended it in my answer), hovewer IMO, for beginner it's a quite good solution, as is the easiest one to start with. Your opinion can differ, however I don't see a reason to downvote.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce based on your comment, I've edited my answer to clarify that `SharedPreferences` is not a target solution.

Comment: Hmm I initially thought he meant when you put app to background (with the process getting terminated) then come back. Which Views *do* handle.  But I guess that was a stretch :D your revised answer is better so I revoked it