# How to derive from a class which is a parceable

Tags: inheritance, kotlin, parcelable

In Android using koltin, having a base class `Filters` which is a Parceable.  It works fine with it.  Now need to have a derived class `DerivedFilter` which overrides the function of `getIGenericHandler()`.

If do not implements its own parceable part,  the override function will be deserialized back.

But when implement its parcelable part it got the complier error: `"Primary constructor call expected"` at

```
   constructor(parcel: Parcel) : super(parcel)
```

why it cannot call the `super(parcel)`?

tried a few and non of them worked (showing comment out in code).

How to derive a class from parcelable and implements its own parceable part?

tried similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621165/in-kotlin-how-to-make-a-derived-class-from-a-parcelable-parent-and-has-implemen), but does not work.

```
    open class Filters() : Parcelable {

        var streamType: String = ""
        // simplified it has map, list members

        constructor(streamTypeValue: String): this() {
           init(streamTypeValue)
        }

        constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {

            val streamTypeValue: String = parcel.readString()
            // simplified, it has map, list to build from the parcel

            init(streamTypeValue)
        }

        protected fun init(streamType: String) {

            this.streamType = streamType
            // simplified, it will pass in map, list to set to the corresponding members

        }

        open fun <T>getIGenericHandler(): IGenericHandler<IData<T>>? {
            return null
        }

        override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
        }

        override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel, flags: Int) {

            dest.writeString(streamType)

        }

        companion object {
            @JvmField val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<Filters> = object : Parcelable.Creator<Filters> {
                override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Filters {
                    return Filters(parcel)
                }

                override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Filters?> {
                    return arrayOfNulls(size)
                }
            }
        }



    }


    class DerivedFilter(streamType: String)
        : Filters (streamType){


        override fun <T>getIGenericHandler(): IGenericHandler<IData<T>>? {

            val h = GenericHandler(null, null)
            return h as IGenericDataHandler<IData<T>>
        }


        private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : super(parcel) {  //<=== got compiler error: "Primary constructor call expected"

        }

        /**
         * private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {}  //<=== got compiler error:

        //None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
        //private constructor DerivedFilter(parcel: Parcel) defined in com.test.DerivedFilter
        //public constructor DerivedFilter(streamType: String)

         // if add
         constructor(): this(){}
         // got error: There's a cycle in the delegate calls chain
        */
        override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
        }

        companion object {
            @JvmField
            val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<DerivedFilter> = object : Parcelable.Creator<DerivedFilter> {
                override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): DerivedFilter {
                    return DerivedFilter(parcel)
                }

                override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<DerivedFilter?> {
                    return arrayOfNulls(size)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use [@Parcelize](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html#parcelable) annotation instead implementing `Parcelable` interface yourself. With `@Parcelize` a `Parcelable` implementation will be generated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `@Parcelize annotation` with which you can save a lot of code for the implementation of Parcelable.

**Setting up Kotlin Android Extensions**

1. The configuration of my gradle is the following:

Build.gradle // app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' // Add this


androidExtensions {
  experimental = true // Add this
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  // ------------------------- KOTLIN ------------------------- //
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.11"

 ... // Other Dependencies

} 


@Parcelize
class Filters(var streamType: String = "") : Parcelable
```

Comment: thanks! but using Parcelize is not a option currently in the project.

Answer (score 0):

this one works, maybe there is better ones?

```
    class DerivedFilter()
        : Filters (){


        override fun <T>getIGenericHandler(): IGenericHandler<IData<T>>? {

            val h = GenericHandler(null, null)
            return h as IGenericDataHandler<IData<T>>
        }

        constructor(streamType: String)
                : this () {

            init(streamType)

        }

        // calling into base::init(parcel)
        private constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
            init(parcel)
        }

        override fun writeToParcel(out: Parcel, flags: Int) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags)
        }

        companion object {
            @JvmField
            val CREATOR: Parcelable.Creator<DerivedFilter> = object : Parcelable.Creator<DerivedFilter> {
                override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): DerivedFilter {
                    return DerivedFilter(parcel)
                }

                override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<DerivedFilter?> {
                    return arrayOfNulls(size)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun describeContents(): Int {
            return 0
        }

    }
```