# How to call an activity function inside a class?

Tags: java, android

I am currently modifying an existing app code. I want to call a function to this class file when the mShakeImage.start() occurs.
How can I call the function inside CallScreen to SingleEventView?

CallScreen

```
*/
package com.st.BlueMS.demos.AccEvent;

import android.Manifest;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.net.Uri;

import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class CallScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

protected void CallingFunction() {

    final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 991"));

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CallScreen.this, 
  Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CallScreen.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);

        } else {

           startActivity(callIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

SingleEventView

```
public class SingleEventView extends LinearLayout implements EventView {


    public SingleEventView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public SingleEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public SingleEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public SingleEventView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    private @DrawableRes int mCurrentIconId;
    private ImageView mEventIcon;
    private TextView mEventText;
    private RepeatAnimator mShakeImage;
    private FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent mCurrentDetectEvent = FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.NONE;
    /**
     * string were write the number of steps
     */
    private String mStepCountTextFormat;


    private void changeIcon(@DrawableRes int icon){
        if(icon==mCurrentIconId)
            return;
        mEventIcon.setImageResource(icon);
        mCurrentIconId=icon;
    }

    private void init(Context context){
        inflate(context, R.layout.view_acc_event_single,this);
        mEventIcon = findViewById(R.id.accEvent_singleEventIcon);
        mEventText = findViewById(R.id.accEvent_singleEventLabel);
        AnimatorSet shakeImage = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
                R.animator.shake);

        mShakeImage = new RepeatAnimator(shakeImage, 5);
        mShakeImage.setTarget(mEventIcon);

        mStepCountTextFormat = getResources().getString(R.string.stepCounterStringFormat);
    }

    @Override
    public void enableEvent(Node.Type type, FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent eventType){
        mCurrentDetectEvent = eventType;
        changeIcon( EventIconUtil.getDefaultIcon(eventType));
        mEventText.setText(null);
    }

    private void changeOrientationIcon(@AccelerationEvent int event) {
        @DrawableRes int newIcon = EventIconUtil.getEventIcon(event);
        if (newIcon != mCurrentIconId) {
            changeIcon(newIcon);
        } else {
            mShakeImage.start();
            Context context = getContext();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Alert")
                    .setMessage("This is an alert")
                    .setNegativeButton("OK", null)
                    .show();


        }

    }



    @Override
    public void displayEvent(@AccelerationEvent int event, int data) {
        if(mCurrentDetectEvent == FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.ORIENTATION &&
                FeatureAccelerationEvent.hasOrientationEvent(event)) {
            changeOrientationIcon(event);
        }else {
            mShakeImage.start();
            Context context = getContext();
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Alert")
                    .setMessage("This is an alert")
                    .setNegativeButton("OK", null)
                    .show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);


        }

        if(mCurrentDetectEvent == 
                   FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.PEDOMETER &&``
                   event==FeatureAccelerationEvent.PEDOMETER && data>=0){

               mEventText.setText(String.format(mStepCountTextFormat,data));
        }
    }



    /**
     * store the current status of the view, if is transparent or not
     * @return object where we store the internal state
     */
    @Override
    public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        //begin boilerplate code that allows parent classes to save state
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        return new SingleEventView.SavedState(superState,mCurrentIconId);
    }//onSaveInstanceState

    /**
     * restore the previous state of the view -> if it is transparent or not
     * @param state object where we have stored the data
     */
    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        //begin boilerplate code so parent classes can restore state
        if(!(state instanceof SingleEventView.SavedState)) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
            return;
        }
        SingleEventView.SavedState ss = (SingleEventView.SavedState)state;
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
        //end

        changeIcon(ss.getIcon());

    }//onRestoreInstanceState


    /**
     * class used for store the internal state
     * see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes
     *
     */
    public class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
        private @DrawableRes int mIconId;

        SavedState(Parcelable superState,@DrawableRes int iconId) {
            super(superState);
            mIconId=iconId;
        }

        private SavedState(Parcel in) {
            super(in);
            this.mIconId = in.readInt();
        }

        @DrawableRes int getIcon(){
            return mIconId;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
            super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
            out.writeInt(mIconId);
        }

        //required field that makes Parcelables from a Parcel
        public final Parcelable.Creator<SingleEventView.SavedState> CREATOR =
                new Parcelable.Creator<SingleEventView.SavedState>() {
                    public SingleEventView.SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                        return new SingleEventView.SavedState(in);
                    }
                    public SingleEventView.SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                        return new SingleEventView.SavedState[size];
                    }
                };
    }//SaveState

}
```

IMPORTANT PART TO ADD THE CALLING FUNCTION

```
@Override
public void displayEvent(@AccelerationEvent int event, int data) {
    if(mCurrentDetectEvent == FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.ORIENTATION &&
            FeatureAccelerationEvent.hasOrientationEvent(event)) {
        changeOrientationIcon(event);
    }else {
        mShakeImage.start();
        Context context = getContext();
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("This is an alert")
                .setNegativeButton("OK", null)
                .show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);
```

**EDIT**

I was able to call the function from callscreen to singleeventview.
But now once the calling function is executed, it does not go back to singleeventview.
How do I achieve this?

**LATEST CALLSCREEN CODE**

public class CallScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")

@Override

protected void onStart() {

```
super.onStart();

final int REQUEST_PHONE_CALL = 1;

Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel: 991"));

//----------------------check for permission before placing the call-----
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CallScreen.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CallScreen.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
} else {
    //------------places the call-----------------------------------------------
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

}

}

**LATEST SINGLEEVENTVIEW CODE**

@Override

```
public void displayEvent(@AccelerationEvent int event, int data) {

   if(mCurrentDetectEvent ==FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.FREE_FALL)

    {
        mShakeImage.start();

        Context context = getContext();

        //-----------test for position of shake image--------------------
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)

                .setTitle("Alert")

                .setMessage("This is an alert")

                .show();

        //---------------call function from CallScreen()-----------------
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);

        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all.

Comment: Basically, when the alert displays, I want to call the calling function which I wrote inside the callscreen java file. I do not know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You want to call the calling function from your other activity and by clicking on the Ok button of the alert dialogue. am I right?

And If I am right then you need to perform the action on Ok button click in alert dialogue.
You just need to create an Object of Calling class so that you can access the method of that class.

```java
@Override
 public void displayEvent(@AccelerationEvent int event, int data) {
if(mCurrentDetectEvent == FeatureAccelerationEvent.DetectableEvent.ORIENTATION &&
        FeatureAccelerationEvent.hasOrientationEvent(event)) {
    changeOrientationIcon(event);
}else {
    mShakeImage.start();
    Context context = getContext();
    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle("Alert")
            .setMessage("This is an alert")
            .setNegativeButton("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(ViewDialog dialog, int id) {
            //do things
            //Here you can create the Objet of your Calling class 
      CallScreen callScreen =  new CallScreen();
      callScreen.CallingFunction();
       }
   });
            .show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);
```

Comment: I am getting an error at ViewDialog - Cannot resolve symbol, getApplicationContext() as well, but that I modified to context.getApplicationContext() which solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

To start an `Activity` you need an `Intent` a `Context`.

```
mShakeImage.start();
Context context = getContext();
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setTitle("Alert")
        .setMessage("This is an alert")
        .setNegativeButton("OK", null)
        .show();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallScreen.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

NOTE:

According to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent))

> Launch a new activity. You will not receive any information about when the activity exits.
>
> Note that if this method is being called from outside of an Activity
>   Context, then the Intent must include the
>   Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag. This is because, without
>   being started from an existing Activity, there is no existing task in
>   which to place the new activity and thus it needs to be placed in its
>   own separate task.
>
> This method throws ActivityNotFoundException if there was no Activity
>   found to run the given Intent.

Comment: I used this code. Now the activity is able to go to callscreen.class, however the calling function is not running? Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the calling function is not running mean?

Comment: The current problem is, using your code, once the mAnimatorShake is triggered, it jumps into the calling function activity. However, it loops there and I cannot get back to SingleEventView. How do I achieve this?

Comment: How did you implement the code? Can you post the latest code which starting `CallScreen`?

Comment: I have posted the latest code. Is it because I am using the onStart() method? If thats the case, How do I run the calling function one time, then go back to SingleEventView once the calling function is executed?

Comment: Try moving into the `onCreate`.