EditTexts are populated with same data after rotation
I have a layout with some EditText, like name, surname, city... I include this layout in another layout a couple of times, so there is two EditText for the name, surname, etc. The problem I face is if I fill in these fields, for example, in the first EditText for the name I add "Tom", and in the second "John", and then I rotate the device, both EditText have "Tom".
Basically, I am facing the same problem than this user: All EditTexts are populated with data from one EditText after rotation and backpressed
As he said, I could manually add the EditText to the main layour instead of using include but that would make the XML very messy.
I could also try the user solution, but I don't like it much either, and keeping in mind that the question is 10 years old, I am wondering if there is a better solution.
Thank you.

This post answered your question. Please take a look and apply solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542333/how-to-prevent-custom-views-from-losing-state-across-screen-orientation-changes

The issue may arise in cases where what you are including contains a ViewGroup, in other words, when there is a parent ViewGroup of the EditText where the specific EditText is. If the "EditText" you are including is actually a layout type that is in a ViewGroup, for example, like a TextInputLayout.
Solution 1
If I remember correctly, you can override these methods so they don't try to restore the states.
override fun dispatchSaveInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>) {
    // Nothing
}

override fun dispatchRestoreInstanceState(container: SparseArray<Parcelable>) {
    // Nothing
}

Solution 2
Set attribute android:saveEnabled to false and use onSaveInstanceState() or a ViewModel
